# How to use PhantomReference in Scala

Tags: scala, garbage-collection

I am trying to implement Phantom Reference in Scala to replace finalize(). I have a file object, which needs to be GC'ed using Phantom Reference. While there are some code samples in java, I am not able to find anything in Scala. I did try writing in Scala like this :

```
val q = new ReferenceQueue()
val phantom = new PhantomReference(file,q)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
found   : java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue[Nothing]
[error]  required: java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue[_ >: java.io.File]
[error] Note: Nothing <: Any, but Java-defined class ReferenceQueue is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     val phantom = new PhantomReference(file,q)
```

I understand I am missing something trivial, but I am not very proficient in Scala. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way type inference works in Scala, `q` is inferred to be of type `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue[Nothing]`, but you want it to be a `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue[File]`, so you need to make this explicit when you create it:

```
val q = new ReferenceQueue[File]()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I can't believe I missed this.

Comment: This still does not answer the original question, which is how to implement PhantomReference in Scala